# Pug Conditional to Include All Subdirectories of a File Path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I want to include a script file for any URL that contains `/edit-post`. Problem is, my editor URL will always be suffixed with a post title like this: `/edit-post/some-post-title`, therefore my Pug conditional never evaluates to true.

In other words, I'm looking for a conditional statement that will be true in both the following example conditions:

```
/edit-post/some-post-title
/edit-post/an-even-better-post-title
```

I have access to the path url variable already, and my conditionals are working fine when it's an exact match, so I'm trying to extend that to suffixed subdirectories. Here's what I'm starting with:

```
if path === '/edit-post'
    //my script file
```

Is there maybe a way to include a regex expression or possibly some sort of "contains" statement in Pug?

I was thinking something like `"/edit-post.*"` or `"edit-post[s/S]"`. Also got desperate and tried using `.indexOf()` which all you folks smarter than me will already know doesn't work in Pug templates!

Maybe there's a better way to achieve this altogether? Searched for hours. Tried a hundred combos. Pug's documentation is sparse.

Side note: I did find this neat little Pug/Jade conditional doc I've been using as a tester. Might be of use: [http://learnjade.com/tour/conditionals/](http://learnjade.com/tour/conditionals/%22Pug%20Tester%22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I recommend You:

1)  to rethink Your routing

2)  create `/layouts/admin` for admin panel layout

3)  create `/admin/posts/edit` view for edit purposes

[image: edit example]

But for Your question here is straightforward example:

```
router.get('/post/:slug/edit', (req, res) => {
  Post  
    .findOne({slug: req.params.slug})
    .exec((err, post) => {
      res.render('post', {includeEdit: true, post});
    });
});
```

- `Post` is mongoose model

and in Your view file:

```
if includeEdit === true
  include partials/edit
```

Comment: Ah! That's super smart. And worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: And thanks for the additional recommendations as well. I do have admin routes for posts and editing as well as modular pug files extending a layout file. Just tried to ask the simplest form of the question and not muddy with too many details about my setup. Thanks again!

Comment: happy to help, if You want to see example app that is in screenshot: https://bitbucket.org/num8er/citymag-az-website  also read about this: https://www.terlici.com/2014/08/25/best-practices-express-structure.html  (;